# Tool Tip is blocked by the POPUP WIndow

Tags: javascript, css

My tool tip is blocked by the POPUP Window .
Please see the image here

http://www.tiikoni.com/tis/view/?id=6ffd82f

As you can see that My Tool tip is blocked by the pop up window .

My CSS for the tooltip is

```
elStyle = 'position:absolute; ;background-color:#fefbd6;height: 75px; position: absolute;top: 50px;width: 150px;font-weight:bold;height: 80px;border-color: #FFFF99 ;';

.flotr-mouse-value {
font-size: 13px;
font-weight:bold;
 }

.flotr-mouse-value:after {
    content:"";
    border-color: #fefbd6 transparent transparent transparent;
    border-style:solid;
    border-width:20px;
    width:0;
    height:0;
    position:absolute;

}
```

Please tell me how to resolve this ??

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To complete thirtydot's answer with the left-hand side positioning of the tooltip.

Normal tooltip:

```
lStyle = 'position:absolute; ;background-color:#fefbd6;height: 75px; position: absolute;top: 50px;width: 150px;font-weight:bold;height: 80px;border-color: #FFFF99 ;';
```

Tooltip located to the left of the cursor:

```
lStyleLeft = 'position:absolute; ;background-color:#fefbd6;height: 75px; position: absolute;top: 50px;left:-150px;width: 150px;font-weight:bold;height: 80px;border-color: #FFFF99 ;';
```

Answer (score 0):

The easiest way would be to make the window slightly wider to fully accommodate the tooltip.

Another way would be to change the tooltip to open on the right hand side of the point if the distance between the point and the right edge of the browser window is less than the width of the tooltip.

Comment: Thank you thirtydot , could you please tell me how to do this ??

Comment: I could if you provided more of your relevant code. The changes would *probably* need to be done with JavaScript - and you haven't posted any. If you *really* want an answer, try making a complete [jsFiddle demo](http://jsfiddle.net/) of your graph.